# Потеря фокуса в div

Tags: html, javascript

Есть div

```
<div id="wre" style="padding: 5px;border: 1px solid #000;" >text</div>
```

Как сделать что бы при потери фокуса менялся текст в этом div ? например если я нажму на этот div то ничего не произойдет , а если нажму за его приделами то там сменится текст

Answer (score 3):

Не?

```
$('body').click(function() {
   $('#wre').text('New text');
});

$('#wre').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам именно в такой последовательности надо? То есть, изменения происходит только после клика на этот элемент и затем за его пределами? Если да, то [вот такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/B2ZSM/).

Comment: нет) так я и сам могу)

Comment: @lisinskiy, так может вы более подробно расскажите о том, что хотели бы в результате? И что у вас не получается сделать самому?